# Find position of cells within a react-virtualized masonry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I am rendering out a masonry. However, I must keep a reference to the positions of the nodes to do spatial indexing.

The best way I can find to do this is a pretty meh method in the `cellRenderer`

```
@hot(module)
export default class ProductsMasonry extends PureComponent {
  // my spatially indexed tree.
  tree: rbush.RBush<BoundingBox> = rbush();

  cellRenderer = ({ key, style, index }) => {
    this.tree.insert({
      minX: parseInt(style.left, 10),
      maxX: parseInt(style.left, 10) + parseInt(style.width, 10),
      minY: parseInt(style.top, 10),
      maxY: parseInt(style.top, 10) + parseInt(style.height, 10),
    });
  }
}
```

Ideally, I want to put this in the `onCellsRendered`, but it only offers `startIndex` and `stopIndex`, so I am not sure how to make use of those to get the size and position of the cell.

How would this be done with react virtualized?